# Issue with view updation in AngularJS directive

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I am using the following directive for 'add tag' functionality in my application:

```
directives.addTag = function ($http) {
    return {
        link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
            element.bind('keypress', function (event) {
                if (event.keyCode == 13) { /*If enter key pressed*/

                    if (!scope.$parent.post) { //For KShare
                        var newTagId = "tagToNote";

                    }
                    else { //For KB
                        var newTagId = "tagToAddFor" + scope.post.meta.id;
                    }
                    var tagValue = element[0].value;

                    if (tagValue == "")
                        return;

                    if (!scope.$parent.post) {
                        scope.$parent.tags.push(tagValue);
                        scope.addTagButtonClicked = false;
                    }
                    else {
                        scope.post.tags.push(tagValue);
                        scope.addTagButtonClicked = false;
                    }
                    scope.$apply();

                    element[0].value = "";
                }
            });
        }
    }
}
```

This is the HTML code for rendering the tags:

```
<div class="tagAdditionSpan" ng-repeat="tag in post.tags" ng-mouseenter="hover = true" ng-mouseleave="hover = false">
            <span>{{tag}}</span>
            <span class="deleteIconSpan" ng-class="{deleteTagIcon: hover}"  ng-click="$parent.deleteTag($index,$parent.$index);"></span>
</div>
```

I have a textbox to add tags when a user types the name of the tag in it and presses 'Enter' key. On page load, I am statically populating 1 tag into the 'tags' array.

I am even able to add tags using the tags and it is reflected in the view. However after adding 2 or 3 tags, it starts misbehaving and the view is no longer updated with the added tags.

I tried debugging this and found that it is being updated in the 'scope.post.tags' array but is not reflected in the view.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What does you console tell you ? (F12 or Shit+Ctrl+i)

Comment: Are you adding any duplicate tags? If you add duplicates you'll break ng-repeat.

Comment: eddiec has a good point, if that is the issue you can get around it by using "track by". See http://docs.angularjs.org/error/ngRepeat:dupes.

Comment: Yes that solved the problem Thanks Erik and Eddiec. By duplicate tags, did you mean 'duplicate tag names' or 'duplicate tag ids'? Because I'm not giving any id for the tags.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the comments received, I was able to solve the issue. 'ng-repeat' used to break the loop on addition of duplicate tags and hence the view was not updated accordingly.

This fixed the issue(added 'track by' in ng-repeat):

```
<div class="tagAdditionSpan" ng-repeat="tag in post.tags track by $index" ng-mouseenter="hover = true" ng-mouseleave="hover = false">
            <span>{{tag}}</span>
            <span class="deleteIconSpan" ng-class="{deleteTagIcon: hover}"  ng-click="$parent.deleteTag($index,$parent.$index);"></span>
</div>
```